# std::string comparison (check whether string begins with another string)

Tags: c++, string, stl, compare

I need to check whether an std:string begins with "xyz". How do I do it without searching through the whole string or creating temporary strings with substr().

Answer (score 163, accepted):

I would use compare method:

```
std::string s("xyzblahblah");
std::string t("xyz")

if (s.compare(0, t.length(), t) == 0)
{
// ok
}
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about compare - this is the best method, but there is no need to use c_str(0 to get a character string

Comment: You can do string s("xyz") == "xyz" too. :)

Comment: Neil, you're absolutely right, I edited answer and removed c_str() call

Comment: Why don't you simply use s.compare(t)?

Comment: @FranckMesirard: That's because by default _compare_ would try to compare the whole length of the passed string against the member data and would return false, while giving the length as the passed parameter's length would make it return true (meaning _std::basic_string::compare_, when used with offset & length, can be made use of like String.BeginsWith() in other libraries.) Without the offset and length, this wouldn't be true.

Comment: This returns true if t is empty.

Comment: @gliderkite As it should ... the empty string is an initial prefix of every string.

Comment: As it should is correct... If you want to rule out empty strings:

if (!t.empty() && !s.compare(0, t.length(), t))

Answer (score 14):

An approach that might be more in keeping with the spirit of the Standard Library would be to define your own begins_with algorithm.

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


template<class TContainer>
bool begins_with(const TContainer& input, const TContainer& match)
{
    return input.size() >= match.size()
        && equal(match.begin(), match.end(), input.begin());
}
```

This provides a simpler interface to client code and is compatible with most Standard Library containers.

Comment: Cool! This should be added to boost!

Comment: @David: If boost is a allowed dependency, see boost::algorithm::[starts_with](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/algorithm/starts_with.html)  — 'Starts with' predicate

Answer (score 10):

Look to the Boost's [String Algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) library, that has a number of useful functions, such as starts_with, istart_with (case insensitive), etc.  If you want to use only part of boost libraries in your project, then you can use bcp utility to copy only needed files

Answer (score 4):

It seems that std::string::starts_with is inside C++20, meanwhile std::string::find can be used

```
std::string s1("xyzblahblah");
std::string s2("xyz")

if (s1.find(s2) == 0)
{
   // ok, s1 starts with s2
}
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer using `std::string::compare` because it makes it easy to check if the string begins with a literal without repeating the literal itself to find its size. And thanks for pointing to the C++20 direct solution.

Comment: If s1 does not begin with s2, this will still try to match it afterwards, which is not as good as compare().

Answer (score 0):

I feel I'm not fully understanding your question. It looks as though it should be trivial:

```
s[0]=='x' && s[1]=='y' && s[2]=='z'
```

This only looks at (at most) the first three characters. The generalisation for a string which is unknown at compile time would require you to replace the above with a loop:

```
// look for t at the start of s
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
  if (s[i]!=t[i])
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, I know how to compare strings in using C functions. My question was about doing it object-oriented way by means of C++ STL.

Comment: There is no C function being used here. And the Standard Library does not preclude you from writing unctions of your own.

Comment: and what if t is shorter than s?

Comment: @jackhab The author of STL says "STL is not object oriented. I think that object orientedness is almost as much of a hoax as Artificial Intelligence." -- http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html

Comment: @vidstige Then the loop terminates when it encounters the terminating NUL in `t`.

Comment: @JimBalter That's probably the stupidest thing Stephanov ever said. OOD/OOP has been prevalent in system development for the last 20 years as a result of its unparalled ability to manage complexity. Generic programming has also become ubiquitous in that time, but it is more likely to be used for internal implementation instead of for high level components and client interfaces. We have learned to use the two together.

Comment: @Neutrino The issue isn't whether Stepanov is right or wrong about OO, it's whether the STL is OO. (It's not, of course.)

Comment: @JimBalter I think that's debatable. STL classes expose their functionality through an interface behind which they hide private implementation and they can be composed and subclassed just like other OO types. Being generic their interface does not fully insulate the client from their implementation to the extent that a non-generic implementation would, but I don't think that means they are not OO at all.

Comment: It's not debatable when its creator says that the STL is not OO ... and when the above argument is utter nonsense; the fact that STL containers are implemented as C++ classes doesn't make the STL OO.