# C++: how to judge if the path of the file start with a given path

Tags: c++, c

I have a path, for example, named

> /my/path/test/mytestpath

, and I want to judge if it start with a given path, for example

> /my/path

Comment: This sounds like a simple [begins with problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931827/stdstring-comparison-check-whether-string-begins-with-another-string) unless you plan on expanding paths (`~` for example)

Comment: Even without expansion, it's not quite that simple, @Joe. The file *string* begins with `/my/pa`, but the *path* does not include it.

Comment: You might need to normalize a path first, especially on a system like UNIX with special wildcards and symbolic links.

Comment: @Joe, yes, it is a more begin with problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the index at which a string was found, with an index of 0 being the start of the string:

```
std::string path("/my/path/test/mytestpath");

// This will check if 'path' begins with "/my/path/".
//
if (0 == path.find("/my/path/"))
{
    // 'path' starts with "/my/path".
}
```

Comment: hmjd, thanks for your help. But I need to judge if the path is start with "/my/path", not only contain.

Comment: This won't quite work though because if path is /my/path1/stuff it will appear to work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph /test/mytestpath/my/path is correct according to std::find. But the OP wants whether it starts with /my/path/

Comment: it works unless the OP wants to write portable code (converting the `/` for different systems).

Comment: @Mahesh No. The code will only find hits at the beginning of the string, not in the middle (but it was missing a trailing slash).

Answer (score 7):

The [C++17 filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is probably the most robust solution. If C++17 is not available to you, [Boost.Filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)  provides an implementation for earlier C++ versions. Try something like:

```
bool isSubDir(path p, path root) 
{
    while(p != path()) {
        if(p == root) {
             return true;
        }
        p = p.parent_path();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1. Probably what zhaojing really wanted to know; the current description sounds like he got stuck halfway through solving the problem.

Comment: It might be nicer to use `equivalent` rather than `operator==`, depending on the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Substring the length of the string ( /my/path ) of the original (/my/path/test/mytestpath ) from the beginning.
2. Check whether two strings are equal.

Comment: You have to consider checking for `/my/path/` or else `/my/pathSomeDeviatingPath/` will be a match. Note the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a string compare of the number of characters in the shorter string.

The fact that the characters match of itself won't mean it is a sub-path because you need to check that the next character in the longer string is a '/'

In C you can use strncmp() which takes a length of characters.

In C++ you can use the same or string compare functions. The find() function will work for this but remember to also check that the next character in the main path is a directory separator.

You could "tokenize" your path but that is likely to not be worth it.

Comment: +1 for the extra check needed (unless you ensure that the shorter path ends with a '/').