# Check if a string contains a string from index to another index

Tags: c++, string

I try to do a interpreter in c++ and I want to do a function that when the user enter type(a) it will give type of the variable a like a is int or bool or string. So my question is I want to know if the first five letter are type( this is the best solution I think in order to do what I want. But my question is how to do this in another way that I do below because this is a very ugly way !

```
if (str.at(0) == 't' && str.at(1) == 'y' && str.at(2) == 'p' && str.at(3) == 'e' && str.at(4) == '(' )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931827/stdstring-comparison-check-whether-string-begins-with-another-string

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is probably using `std::string::compare` or `std::string::find`; I suppose a google search with terms "c++ string start with" would have brought you directly to examples with advantages and disadvantages.

However, when writing very simple parsers, the tokenizer `strtok` from c's string library might me an easier way. `strtok` subsequently splits a string into tokens, where each call to `strtok` returns the next token. Characters separating tokens are passed as parameter to `strtok`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    std::string str = "type(a)";

    if (str.compare(0,5,"type(") == 0) {
        // string starts exactly with `type(`;
        // note: 'type (' would not match...
    }

    char* analyzeStr = strdup(str.c_str());
    char *token = strtok(analyzeStr, "(");
    if (token && strncmp(token, "type", strlen("type")) == 0) {
        // command starts with "type(" or "type  ("
        token = strtok(NULL, ")");
        if (token) {
            // value between brackets
            printf("analyzing type of '%s'", token);
        }
    }
    free(analyzeStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Read the documentation on strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) before using it. It comes with a number of caveats stemming from being designed to solve simpler problems in simpler times and may not be suitable. For example note the need to `char* analyzeStr = strdup(str.c_str());` and `free(analyzeStr);` to get around `strtok`'s destructive effects of the source string.